# Can а verb and related noun be used in the same sentence?

Tags: verbs, writing-style

Here is a sentence: "Without those measurements, we cannot measure if we are progressing in the right direction."

*measure* is clearly a verb here, but what part of speech is *measurement*? (abstract noun?)

The use of *measurement* and *measure* in the same sentence does not seem like good style to me. Is this good style? I feel like the *measure* should be replaced with a synonym because *measurement* is in the same sentence. Is there a style rule or guideline that says this?

Comment: you measure to get the measurements.  It doesn’t require measurements in order to measure.  without measurements you can’t ***determine*** whether you are progressing...

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence -

> Without those measurements, we cannot measure if we are progressing in
>   the right direction.

- does not make much *technical* sense. You cannot measure directions. Progress can be measured or gauged. Direction can be judged, determined, figured out, etc. Consider:

> Without those measurements, we cannot **judge with any certainty** if we
>   are progressing in the right direction.

Or -

> Without those measurements, we cannot **determine** whether we are
>   progressing in the right direction.

Etc.